# Is there a way to dynamic import components in _app.js in next js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

for making the header and footer common in my project I put my header and footer components in _app.js file .

below is my _app.js file -

```
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from 'next/app';
import Layout from 'components/Layout';
import createStore from 'store/createStore';
import MetaInfo from 'components/common/meta-info';
const PwaHeader = dynamic(() => import('components/mobile/pwa-header/PwaHeader'), { ssr: false});
const PwaBottomNav = dynamic(() => import('components/mobile/pwa-bottomNav/PwaBottomNav'), { ssr: false});
const DesktopHeader = dynamic(() => import('components/desktop/desktop-header/DesktopHeader'), { ssr: false});
const DesktopFooter = dynamic(() => import('components/desktop/desktop-footer/DesktopFooter'), { ssr: false});
// import PwaHeader from 'components/mobile/pwa-header/PwaHeader';
// import PwaBottomNav from 'components/mobile/pwa-bottomNav/PwaBottomNav'
// import DesktopHeader from 'components/desktop/desktop-header/DesktopHeader';
// import DesktopFooter from 'components/desktop/desktop-footer/DesktopFooter';
class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
        return {
            pageProps: {
                ...(Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {}),
            }
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps, store, router } = this.props;
        const { seoData, noIndex, noFollow, canonicalUrl, ampUrl, currentUrl, microData, pageToken, locDataObj, isCmhWebView, footerLinks, cityList, config, deviceCategory, pageName } = router.query;
        const isMobileView = (deviceCategory === 'mobile' || deviceCategory === 'tablet');
        const isDesktopView = (deviceCategory === 'desktop');
        if (locDataObj) {
            locDataObj.config = config;
        }
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Layout>
                    {
                        (isMobileView) ? <PwaHeader headerData={locDataObj} pageToken={pageToken} /> : (isDesktopView) ? <DesktopHeader headerData={locDataObj} pageToken={pageToken} /> : ''
                    }
                    <Component router={router} {...pageProps} />
                    <MetaInfo seoData={seoData} noIndex={noIndex} noFollow={noFollow} canonicalUrl={canonicalUrl} ampUrl={ampUrl} microData={microData} />
                    {
                        (isMobileView) ? <PwaBottomNav selectedCity={locDataObj.cityName} currentUrl={currentUrl} pageName={pageName} pageToken={pageToken} /> : (isDesktopView) ? <DesktopFooter cityList={cityList} footerLinks={footerLinks ? footerLinks : ''} isCmhWebView={isCmhWebView} /> : ''
                    }
                </Layout>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default withRedux(createStore)(
    withRouter(MyApp)
)
```

Since I only want to render either mobile or desktop headers and footers based on isMobileView flag. Initially I tried using static imports (right now commented imports in the code) but all the .js files loaded in the browser(of both mobile and desktop).
Then I tried doing the dynamic imports but the issue I am facing is that I need to do the same dynamic import in all the child components present in the header and footer components. Since there are scss files as well so due to dynamic import those files not loaded initially and the css is not getting reflected.
Is there a better way to fix this issue?